# How do I allow a user to manage users in .Net MVC 5.0 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have built an MVC application using ASP.NET Identity 2.0. I have done so before many times and I have no problem registering users, setting passwords, etc. It is all done for me by the template.

However, my client has asked to be able to manage users themselves. I assumed this would be as easy as creating a controller and views for the AspNetUsers table in the database. Its not though. For starters I have to create a model before I can create a controller and view, but given that it is code-first that makes no sense really. I tried creating a view-model so as the database wouldn't want to be updated, but then EF doesn't recognise the AspNetUsers as there is no model so it can't connect.

If I sound confused it is because I am. Can anyone shed some light. All I want is a view showing all the users and allowing the admin to add or delete users of the application. I know there will be a few gotchas like setting passwords etc, but I can figure that out later.

I don't want to have to roll my own user table if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a model;

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

Extend your `AccountController`;

```
public class AccountController : Controller 
{ 
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]           
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        return View(/* Get all users using UserManager */);
    }

    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]   
    public ActionResult Create() 
    { 
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]   
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(UserModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if(result.Succeeded)
            {
                //handle success
            }
            else 
            {
                //handle otherwise
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, create the views `Index` and `Create` in `Views/Account` and map them to `UserModel`.

Same goes for `Edit` and `Delete`, but I'll leave those as exercise :)

Comment: that got me started on the right track anyway. I created a view that used AppName.Models.ApplicationUser as the model and then returned UserManager.Users from the AccountController controller. That has given me the index anyway. I'll do the edit later. Thank you